# Выравнивание по центру только пунктов меню

Tags: html, css

Нужно выравнять по центру только пункты меню, с логотипом ничего не делать Добавлять классы к пунктам меню? Думала через not, но что то не получается. Спасибо

```css
.up {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(110, 22, 62, .9);
  z-index: 5;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
}

nav .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

ul:not([class]) li {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>a:not(:only-child) {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #6d163d;
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #6d163d;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-1>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-2>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu-2>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.submenu-2>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <nav class="wrapp">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Наши услуги</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
          <li><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Меню</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">О компании</a>
        <ul class="submenu-2">
          <li><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас в коде примера ошибка была `<a href="">Контакты</a>` закрывающий тег </a> был без слеша

Answer (score 0):

Не понял где вы хотите его разместить, но в любом случае для этого нужно использовать `position:absolute` , после этого вы сможете управлять позиционированием элемента с помощью свойств `left right top bottom`

```css
.up {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(110, 22, 62, .9);
  z-index: 5;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
}

nav .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

ul:not([class]) li {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>a:not(:only-child) {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #6d163d;
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #6d163d;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu-1>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-2>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu-2>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu-1>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.submenu-2>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #6d163d;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.logo{
position:absolute;
right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">



  <nav class="wrapp">
    <ul class="menu">

      <li><a href="#">Наши услуги</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
          <li><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Меню</a></li>
      <li>
     
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">О компании</a>
        <ul class="submenu-2">
          <li><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Контакты<a></li>   
   </ul>
      
     </nav>
      <a href="" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
 </div>
```

А вообще в ваших стилях и разметке очень много лишнего и не понятного, все вперемешку, это можно было сделать так, хотя бы:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.up {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(110, 22, 62, .9);
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.menupoints {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  list-style: none !important;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.menupoints>a {
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translatey(50%);
}

li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.submenu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.submenu>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6d163d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  background: red;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<nav class="up">
  <li class="menupoints"><a href="#">Наши услуги</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">УСЛУГА 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">УСЛУГА 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">УСЛУГА 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menupoints"><a href="">Меню</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">МЕНЮ 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">МЕНЮ 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">МЕНЮ 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menupoints"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menupoints"><a href="">Контакты</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <a href="" class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
</nav>
```